# Unable to get kubelet config by alpha phase

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I'm trying to get kubelet config.yaml file on my broken production cluster with no luck. The command I am using is:

```
kubeadm alpha phase kubelet config write-to-disk --config=/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml
```

This returns the following error:

```
no InitConfiguration or ClusterConfiguration kind was found in the YAML file
```

Could somebody please help me resolve this? Thanks.

Comment: I think u can only do it if the cluster was made with kubeadm with config.yml file

Comment: did u create the cluster with kubeadm init --config somefile.yml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically need to print the config prior (The one that contains the `InitConfiguration` and the `ClusterConfiguration`:

```
$ kubeadm config print-default > cluster.yaml
```

Then:

```
$ kubeadm alpha phase kubelet config write-to-disk --config=cluster.yaml
```